# NSCFConstantString objectAtIndex: error in grouped table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this (Settings Page):

```
Logout = Logout;
Social =     (
    Facebook,
    Twitter
);
Terms =     (
    "Privacy Policy",
    "Terms of Service"
);
```

Then the right ordered array:

```
`Social, Terms, Logout`
```

Right now I have three sections.  From the cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm trying to do this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[_settingsOptions objectForKey:
    [_arrayKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And I'm getting the NSCFConstantString error.  When I manually put in numbers for indexes, everything displays fine.  But from the datasource method I get this error.  Can someone find the error?

Comment: Is the value of the line `Logout = Logout` also an Array?

Comment: @MABVT You're right...when I was making the dictionary, I didn't do `[NSArray arrayWithObject:]` for the "Logout" option...thanks for suggesting!

Comment: NSLog() the dictionary and put that in the question. Also, breakup the single statement into separate intermediate statements, it makes it easier to debug and understand. See example "non answer."

Answer (score 1):

Example code as an answer (which it isn't) for formatting:

```
NSString *s1 = [_arrayKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray  *s2 = [_settingsOptions objectForKey:s1];
NSString *text = [s2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = text;
```

The real code would have the actual types (I guessed) and descriptive names instead to s1 s2, text.
Just giving the intermediates types and descriptive names might make the error clear.

Now each step can be independently debugged and if desired NSLog'ed.